# How do I loop over rows in a Dataframe and perform calculations on specific rows based on conditional statements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have this dataframe below:

| ID | Day | Month | Year | Status | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021 | open | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021 | open | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021 | close | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021 | close | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021 | NaN | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2021 | standing | NaN |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2021 | close | 15 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2021 | open | 16 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2021 | standing | NaN |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2021 | close | 65 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2021 | NaN | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | open | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | open | 2 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | close | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | close | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | standing | 50 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | open | 15 |
| 3 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | close | 16 |
| 3 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |
| 4 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | close | 65 |
| 4 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | open | 10 |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 2021 | open | 65 |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 2021 | open | 20 |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 2021 | standing | 0 |

[Raw dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mLCI.png)

I want to define a loop that will loop over the 'Status' column for every specific ID and if it finds the string 'Standing', then it calculates the mean of the last 10 rows in the 'Values' column or if it finds the string 'Standing' again prior to the 10 previous rows, then it takes the average of all the rows in the 'Values' column until the row it found the Standing string and places it in a new column in the same row where it found 'Standing'. Something similar to the image below. Thank you so much.

| ID | Day | Month | Year | Status | Values | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021 | open | 10 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021 | open | 2 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021 | close | 4 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021 | close | 3 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021 | NaN | 0 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2021 | standing | NaN | 3.8 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2021 | close | 15 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2021 | open | 16 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2021 | standing | NaN | 15.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2021 | close | 65 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2021 | NaN | 10 |  |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | open | 10 |  |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | open | 2 |  |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | close | 4 |  |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |  |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | close | 3 |  |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | standing | 50 | 20.6 |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |  |
| 3 | 6 | 3 | 2021 | open | 15 |  |
| 3 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | close | 16 |  |
| 3 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | open | NaN |  |
| 4 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | close | 65 |  |
| 4 | 7 | 3 | 2021 | open | 10 |  |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 2021 | open | 65 |  |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 2021 | open | 20 |  |
| 4 | 8 | 3 | 2021 | standing | 0 | 27.3 |

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCDEs.png)

Comment: Please post your data as plain text, not as an image. Also, what have you tried so far to solve the issue?

Comment: You could get the index of all rows that contain 'Standing'. Afterwards, do a slice iloc on the previous rows and use iterrows on them where you treat the exceptions.

Comment: @drake10k can you please show me in a code format? Thanks

Comment: def get_index_of_rows_containing_string(df, column_name, string_to_search):
    # get the index of all rows that contain a specific string in a pandas dataframe column and ignore NaN values
    return df[df[column_name].str.contains(string_to_search, na=False)].index.tolist()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this approach

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rollingbyid.csv')
df['New Column'] = ''

std = df[df.Status=='standing']

for i,row in std.iterrows():
    matchid = df[df.ID==row['ID']]
    ms = matchid['Values'].loc[i-10:i].mean(skipna=True)
    df['New Column'][i] = ms
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much @Pankaj. I really appreciate it : )